# Convert a string to number, string has more than 16 digit using + or ParseFloat is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to convert a string with more than 16 digit to number. But in javascript it is not allowed according to various article I read. Reference of some are here
[How to convert a long string (more than 16 digits) into numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70966575/how-to-convert-a-long-string-more-than-16-digits-into-numbers)

[facing an issue with parseFloat when input is more than 16 digits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35681127/facing-an-issue-with-parsefloat-when-input-is-more-than-16-digits)

https://2ality.com/2012/07/large-integers.html

Below is the code I tried.

```
let  x= "123456789123456789"
console.log(parseInt(x))
console.log(parseFloat(x))
console.log(Number(x))
console.log(+x)

let  y= "1234567891234567.34"
console.log(parseInt(y))
console.log(parseFloat(y))
console.log(Number(y))
console.log(+y)
```

I want the exact numbers as I use string to display in ContentEditable field and when I save the data I need to pass it as a number. As it is related to banking the same numbers are important.

Is there any way I can solve this issue or any library I can use to solve this problem

Comment: You'll have to use a library if you want to represent numbers with more than 16 digits in javascript, [bignumber.js](https://mikemcl.github.io/bignumber.js/) should work for you.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt

Comment: @Kermode what's wrong with the native BigInt?

Comment: "Related to banking", as in is this an account or transaction number? If so, consider using a string instead of a number. If you are not doing arithmetic with a number, store it as a string.

Comment: @Kermode BigInt wont support decimal part, you can check my examples above

Comment: @ashwini  That is why money is often handled as pennies / cents rather than pounds/dollars/euros

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try Use the BigInt, multiply with number or add,minus float number.

```
let  x= "123456789123456789";
console.log(BigInt(x));
console.log(1*x);

let  y= "1234567891234567.34";
console.log(0.01-0.01+y);
```

https://dev.to/sanchithasr/7-ways-to-convert-a-string-to-number-in-javascript-4l

Comment: BigInt won't work for numbers with decimals.

Comment: @ashwini if my answer helped you please tell me and mark it.

Comment: This won't work as it will  let  y= "1234567891234567.34";
console.log(y*1); for this answer will be 1234567891234567.2. I want the exact number as input

Comment: I changed the code. its not so clean but it works.

Comment: this works Thank you for the help. I am checking if the n at the end of big number can be removed.